# Proof for the linear dependence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let there be a vector space V and a subset A={a1... ar} ⊂ V. Leit it also be the case that 1≤ i ≤ r. 
Show that the elements of A are linearly dependent, when there does exist an index i∈{1,...,r} and real numbers λj   j∈{1,...,r}, j≠i so that the following is true:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/i55Eh.jpg)

If somebody could help me out, I would be very happy. My guess is that I have to subtract ai from the sum of the other elements to get the zweo, but I have no idea how a formally correct answer might look like.

Comment: The question is not clear. I guess you don't want to fix $1\leq i \leq r$ but prove that that the elements of A are linearly dependent if and only if there exist an index $i∈{1,...,r}$ and real numbers $λ_j, j∈{1,...,r}, j≠i$ (assuming the vector space is real) so that $a_i=\sum_{j\neq i} \lambda_j a_j$

Comment: If this is the case, use the definition of linear dependence and try to guess what should be the $\lambda_j$.

Answer (score 0):

It is essentially the definition of [linearly dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence):

> A set of vectors is said to be linearly dependent if at least one of the vectors in the set can be defined as a linear combination of the others